# Testing error: No module named 'app.post'

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm trying to use Django's unit test feature. I've added a blank `test.py` under `app/post/tests` (along with `__init__.py`). However when I run `python manage.py test post` it returns `ImportError: No module named 'app.post'`. Any idea why it says this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you didn't add your application name in **settings.py** file. Add your app in **setting.py** file and error will be fixed.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'post',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: I have already added it in `INSTALLED_APPS` - it's still not working